# Copy only newest folder via batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need to copy over only the latest folder from a folder. All the examples I see online are for copying just the newest file. Is it possible to copy over the latest folder via batch file?

Answer (score 1):

```
CD folder
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`DIR /A:D /O:-D`) DO (
 XCOPY "%%A" "new folder" /E /H /K /Y
 GOTO:OUT
)

:OUT
```

Change directory to the folder in question. Use a `FOR` loop over the listing of all folders in current folder, arrange them by date with the newest on top, then copy all the contents of that folder to the new destination (/E Copies all directories and subdirectories even if empty, /H include all hidden and system files, /K keeps attribute settings, /Y suppresses the prompt to copy), then leave the loop after the first iteration (i.e. newest file)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx)?

### Edit to address downvote

```
robocopy .\src .\dest /e /xo /dcopy:T
```

Options

```
/xo 
Excludes older files.

/e  
Copies subdirectories. Note that this option includes empty directories.

/dcopy:T    
Copies directory time stamps.
```

Comment: Updated to address downvote. If there's an issue with the answer, please comment on why it is not feasible, does not address the question or is incorrect.